# Home not showing in yoast breadcrumb

Tags: plugins, breadcrumb

I have created a page named home and assigned a template file named Homepage to it. I am using `yoast breadcrumb` to display breadcrumb. But Home is not included in it. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

These breadcrumbs rely on the parent/child structures you make in your website.

So in order to make "Home" show up in the breadcrumbs, be sure it is set as the parent of the other pages you have and want to show as child items of Home